# How to pass command line argument scala

Tags: scala

How to read Scala command-line arguments?

Comment: Example : try this  following into a new file named helloarg.scala

println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")

then run scala helloarg.scala "Planet") 

result : Hello Planet!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the one some repos are doing it ? Here is Spark: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/05168e725d2a17c4164ee5f9aa068801ec2454f4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala